# Can we limit the value of a response variable in any machine learning algorithm?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am working on a problem in which my response variable is a relative power whose value cannot go beyond 100%. When I use linear regression or any other machine-learning algorithms, the predicted value goes beyond 100% and I want to limit that to 100%. Is there any way we can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the meaning of your response variable, considering you are using linear regression. But in a general function `y=f(x)`, you can add a `Softmax` function `y=Softmax(f(x))` to make sure y in (0, 1). If you replace `Softmax` with `sigmoid` and use it for regression, then you get a `Logistic regression`, they you can limit the response value to (0, 1).